# How to display images from an array

Tags: objective-c, arrays

Recently, I had a problem that really annoyed me.
The reason was I wanted to put an image in an array and display each in a collectionview cell, but it doesn't work.

This was my code

```
NSMutableArray *imagearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[imagearray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img_sort-1"]];
[imagearray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img_sort-2"]];
[imagearray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img_sort-3"]];
[imagearray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img_sort-4"]];
[imagearray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img_sort-5"]];
[imagearray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img_sort-6"]];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 30, 30)];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imagearray];
[customView addSubview:imageView];
```

and because I want to display the array in this section

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

}
```

Does anyone have a good idea??

Comment: What exactly is the issue? What's the specific error? Assuming your image names are correct, you're loading up the array correctly

Comment: Do you want the images in the cells of a collection (like you mention at the top of your question) or in the header of a table view (like you mention at the bottom)? Additionally, assigning an array of images to a single `UIImageView` only makes sense if the images are frames in an animation, in which case you would assign the array to the `animationImages` property (or possibly to the `highlightedAnimationImages` property)